# How to sort an associative array by sort function in Javascript with the same ID?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, associative-array

```
function updateUld(pUldValues){
    if (pUldValues != null){
        pUldValues.sort(compareSort);
    }
}

function compareSort (first,second){
    var ret = 0;
    var uldA = first[1]; //TOTO
    var UldB = second[1]; //MAMA
      if (uldA.substring(0,1) == "T"){
            ret = compareRefUldRefUldTULD(uldA, UldB);
        }
        if (uldA.substring(0,1) == "M" ||
                uldA.substring(0,1) == "A"){
            ret = compareRefUldRefUldMix(uldA, UldB);
        }
        if (uldA.substring(0,1) == "L"){
            ret = compareRefUldRefUldLoose(uldA, UldB);
        }
        if(ret==0){
            if (UldB.substring(0,1) == "M" ||
                    UldB.substring(0,1) == "A"||
                    UldB.substring(0,1) == "T" ||
                    UldB.substring(0,1) == "L"){
                ret = -1 ; 
            }else{
                ret= UldB.localeCompare(uldA);
            }
        }
        return -ret ;
}
```

`pUldValues` before sort contains `555 : MAMA + 556 : TOTO` ...

After sort is `: 0 : TOTO + 1 : MAMA` ...

I would like that I have the same sorted but in this format `: 555 : TOTO + 556 : MAMA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an Array as a Map and you can't order an Object.

But since ECMAScript 2015 you can use the **Map** object which guarantees the order of the keys. [See the Map documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Here a rapid exemple with an object in input:

```js
var myMap = {
  "555":  "TOTO",
  "556":  "MAMA",
  "557":  "PAPA",
  "1":    "ZOE",
  "2":    "ABC"
};

function sortMap(map){
 // Get the keys of map
 var keys= Object.keys(map);
 
 // Sort the keys by the value
 keys.sort(function(a,b){
  var aValue = map[a];
  var bValue = map[b];
  
  if(aValue < bValue) return -1;
  if(aValue > bValue) return 1;
  return 0;
  
 });
 
 // Rebuild the map from the sorted key.
 var result = new Map;
 for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  result.set(keys[i], map[keys[i]]);
 }
 
 return result;
}

var sortedMap = sortMap(myMap);

// Snipet display
sortedMap.forEach(function(value, key){
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')).innerHTML = key+'=>'+value;
});
```

Comment: You can also create your own SortableMap. ;-)